# meteor easysearch search by ID

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I like to ask about using meteor easysearch to search through mongodb collection. The problem is I have this collection called station.
In mongodb, the collection station has fields like:
_id: "xxxxxxx",
name: "station1",
province: "xxxxxx",
district: "xxxxxx",
Noted that the xxxxx represent the id from another collection.

const STATION = new Mongo.Collection('station');

const SearchingIndex = new EasySearch.Index({
    collection: STATION,
    fields: ['name','province','district'],
    engine: new EasySearch.MongoDB()
  });

using the above meteor code, I can search through the collection STATION by the field name, province and district. The problem is province and district are passed by their ID from another collection. So, I will have to search in the input field by their ID too. The question is how can I search by their name instead of the ID? Thank you.

Comment: I have never used easysearch, but it seems to me like what you are trying to do would not work. The problem is that the only thing you have in your immediate collection `STATION` is the ids for province and district.  You would need to have their names to make this work. Unless easysearch has some mechanism for following id references, like maybe dotted notation like `province.name`, then the best approach might be to create an aggregate collection with the data you want to search on. This is a trick used often with a lot of search frameworks like Elasticsearch.

Comment: @CodeChimp, thank you for your comment. I thought that it wouldn't work too but my boss kept digging me to make it worked that way. Anyway, one question...in that STATION collection which is in mongodb, would it be legal or correct if I make a province name field in it ? My colleague said, the data would be duplicated since we already have a province collection that has its name. So like, in province collection there is this name called "province A" and in STATION collection there is this field province_name containing "province A" too. Thank you for your time :)

Comment: Well, that is more of a philosophical argument, IMHO. In the old world of RDBMS, the idea of "normalization" was considered good practice, but my experience with NoSQL DBs is that is not necessarily the case. That said, the downside of duplicating the data is that you have to maintain the duplicated data. Switch to how most search frameworks like Elasticsearch or Solr work in production, and you will find duplication of data is not only the norm, it's considered best practice. So, I would argue that having a separate collection to search off of would not be bad practice at all.

Comment: @CodeChimp thank you Chimp, You have been a great help with the idea. I thought that too of what could go wrong if that happen, It would make life alot easier.